# Difference between Limited Broadcast Address and Direct Broadcast address?

Tags: networking, ip

It has got something to the with the local network but I am not sure. Can anyone clear up this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, in the usual IPv4 + Ethernet scenario there are three different kinds of broadcasts:

1. **local/limited IP broadcast** to 255.255.255.255 - this broadcast reaches all nodes within the local broadcast domain; it is not forwarded by a router
2. **directed IP subnet broadcast** to the subnet address with all hosts bits set to "1", e.g. 192.168.1.255 for the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet - this broadcast reaches all nodes within the (possibly remote) subnet's broadcast domain; even though it is not forwarded by default on most routers, they are often configured to do so (actually, only the last-hop router can judge that this is a directed broadcast; intermediate routers handle the address as unicast)
3. **Ethernet broadcast** to FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF - this broadcast also reaches all nodes on the local broadcast domain and is the method of layer 2 transport used by the former two L3 broadcasts; a local IP broadcast directly translates to an Ethernet broadcast whereby a directed IP subnet broadcast is first routed to the destination network and then wrapped in an Ethernet broadcast by the last router (actually, any MAC address with the I/G bit set - the least significant bit in the first octet - is treated as broadcast/multicast by Ethernet, but not necessarily by the connected NICs)